# Including shared styling within NativeScript app using angular.json stylePreprocessor

Tags: typescript, nativescript, angular6, nativescript-angular, angular-schematics

I'm attempting to use the Angular 6's `stylePreprocessorOptions` so I can simply `@import 'app'` to import branding/other shared stylings into a component.

My nativescript project exists within a NxWorkspace setup, which itself contains an `angular.json`.

The documentation from `@nativescript/schematics` says to generate a new `angular.json` file within the NativeScript projects root, which I have done but also I have placed a clone of the definition within my NxWorkspace root's `angular.json` file as it's unclear to me which is used.

The `angular.json` file's content can be found here: https://hastebin.com/zajiviqoyi.json

When attempting to use `@import "app"` it tells me it cannot find the `app` relative to the file where I have done the import line. In my other app setups, but NativeScript in this instance appears to be ignoring my configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I was able to solve this myself.

I had to edit the `webpack.config.js`, specifically the `sass-loader`.

If you change the `sass-loader` part of the `.scss` rules, you can add `includePaths` to achieve a fallback file resolution for sass.

```
{
    loader: "sass-loader",
    options: {
        includePaths: ["assets/sass"]
    }
}
```

this means I can now `@import 'app'` and NativeScript will find the file outside of it's own directory.

As a warning, this doesn't include the file-extension system NativeScript boasts, so you cannot append `.tns` for a NativeScript specific file.

`node-sass` (sass-loader) does support a `loader` function of which you can use to emulate this functionality if you require.